# Back Button issue in ASP.NET MVC Web Application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, browser

It is kind of a difficult to explain problem.

Let me describe you a scenario.

1. I have Home Page, Registration Page, Login Page and Dashboard page
2. When I register for the application from Register page and hit submit. Application will process request and will redirect me on Dashbord with User logged in. Now, The issue comes. When i hit back button. I get the Registration page with fields filled by values. This should not happen.
3. When i login to system and from dashboard i hit back of browser. it will show me login page. This also should not happen.

I hope it makes it clear what I am looking for.

Few Possible solutions I tried:

1. use a Proxy page. Similar to what many mail services are doing. But in MVC 3 it will not detect page load event and there is very less control on page.
2. use javascript function on a proxy page window.history.forward()
3. Expire proxy page once rendered.

I am not totally convinced with above solution. I was hoping to get some best practices of doing this in a systematic way and elegant solution to problem.

Please help me with your suggestions on existing solution that i am using as well as if you have some great working solution. Please share it.

Thanks All.

FYI.. I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 for development.

Comment: why try change behaviour that users expect?

Comment: Betty It is common behavior in many of the application where you don't show Registration page in back button click. You may try using gmail.com registration page. My point is once user has registered he should not be shown Registration page on back button instead moved back to Dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

Use history.js to control the history.back() event. You just replace the state of the last page to point to the dashboard or the page you want (inside your web app; inter-domain is prohibited for security reasons). When the user clicks the back button the defined page is loaded instead of the login page.

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

The proxy solution is too complicated for this kind of UI interaction. The client-side control is the best approach for your solution. The HTML5 reference define the History API for that (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html). Unfortunately not all the browsers implement it right now; that's because the history.js script exists.

Comment: This is similar solution that we use using window object in javascript. this just adds few features from HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

In the Controller/Action method for the register and login page check if the user is already logged in and redirect to eg. the Dashboard.

Something like this depending on how you do your authentication.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
  //If already logged in no need to show register page again
  if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
    return Redirec("Dashboard");

  return View();
}
```

Edit: Updated answer to fix commented issue

I created a Partial view with the following content

```
<input type="hidden" id="reloader" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (document.getElementById("reloader").value === "reload")
      window.location.reload();
  else
      document.getElementById("reloader").value = "reload"
</script>
```

You can then include that with `@Html.Partial('PartailViewName')` in your Register and Login views.

Since the DOM is cached when you use the back button the script above will reload the page if the user uses the back button.

If used together with my first answer you will get the behavior you wanted.

Comment: Yes, We tried that. But, the issue is. Page is in Browser's cache so it is not going to server for any interaction. So, this approach will not work.